# Убрать переносы на новую строку

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Прошу, подскажите, как убрать переносы на новую строку в зашифрованном тексте (очень мешает при  расшифровке):
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=

Comment: @Nofate пробовал, но не помогает(

Comment: @Nofate а нет! я просто не внимательный)

Comment: @Nofate спасибо, за решение)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почему не воспользоваться [StringReplace](http://www.delphibasics.ru/StringReplace.php)?

*Обновление*

[[@АлександрЪ](/users/18395/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8A)](/users/18395/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8A), вы хотите сказать, что если вышеуказанную строку положить со всеми переносами в переменную `before`, то после выполнения

```
  after := StringReplace(StringReplace(before, #10, '', [rfReplaceAll]), #13, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

в `after` останутся переносы строк?